# Show other views in a PreferenceActivity (Android)

Tags: java, android, preferences

In one of the entries of my PreferenceActivity I'd like to put an horizonal progress bar.

Is posible do that? If yes How can I do it? (I only see the option for adding Preference views)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a custom preference.

Check out the tutorial in this post:

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

or, even better:

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html